# mqtt between python and node.js sends only one message

Tags: python, node.js, mqtt

I am new to mqtt and python system and I am trying to do some heavy computations in python and send the results to a node.js server.

Every time I run node.js script i get only one result. Here is my simple 
code:

simple_mqtt.py

```
message = "Hello"
x=0
def add():
    global x
    x = x + 1

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("mid: "+str(mid))

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("main/app")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global message
    message = msg.payload

client = paho.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.connect("192.168.2.4", 1883)
client.loop_start()
while True:
    if message=="Start":
        print message
        add()
        client.publish("main/app",x)
    elif message=="Stop":
        print message
        client.publish("main/app","Ended")
    time.sleep(1)
```

and the node.js:

```
var mqtt    = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://192.168.2.4:1883');

client.on('connect', function () {
  client.subscribe('main/app');
  client.publish('main/app', 'Start');
});
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  // message is Buffer
  console.log(message.toString());
});
```

What I have to modify to get continuous responses from the python until I send the message "Stop"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same topic for both control and output.

So after receiving a message with `Start` your code publishes `1` to the `main/app` topic and this is immediately received by the python code in `on_message` and sets `message` to `1`

So the next time round the loop `message` is `1` so none of the if statements match.

Comment: Thank you! I created different topics for sending the values, and now I am able to control the flow of my program.